# How do I rewrite a request URL and keep info in same request with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a REST API for `songs` resources, they got an `id` and a `title`, admins can perform `GET /songs/:id` directly, but common users can only access through `GET /songs/:title`.

So if a common user tries to access to a resource like:

```
{
  "id":9248,
  "title": "Hala Madrid"
}
```

By requesting `GET /songs/9248` he should be redirected to `GET /songs/hala_madrid`.

So I could have two different route handlers, and repeat the query. But I really don't want to query twice. So I thought I could reset url and assign the found song to `req.song`.

I tried setting up the following routes and implement a single `get` controller method:

```
router.get('/:id([0-9]+)', songs.get);

router.get('/:title', songs.get);


function get(req, res, next) {
  let { id, title} = req.params;
  console.log(id, title);
  let permalink = id || title;
  let field = isNaN(permalink) ? 'title' : 'id';
  if (req.song) {
    let { song } = req;
    return res.render('app', {song, title: 'song', page: 'song'});
  }
  queries.getSong(field, permalink).then(result => {
    let song = result[0];
    if (req.session.user.role === 'user' && field === 'id') {
      req.song = song;
      req.url = `/songs/${song.title}`;
      return next();
    }
    return res.render('app', {song, title: 'song', page: 'song'});
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({error: err});
  });
}
```

I'm a bit lost as it's ending up in unhandled error, I dont know how *reload* the request to be handled again.

Comment: You could just create a small little cache that held the last N queries so after the redirect the query will likely be in the cache and you will save the database hit.  Also, no need for duplicating code in two separate routes.  You can just make a common function that each route calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but do you have to have two parameters?

```
router.get('/songs/:idortitle', function(req,res,next) {
    const permalink = req.params.idortitle;
    const songQuery !isNaN(permalink) && !req.session.user.role ==='user' ? queries.getSong('id',permalink) :queries.getSong('title',permalink);

    songQuery.then(result => {
        res.render('app', {song, title: 'song', page: 'song'});
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(err);
       return res.status(500).json({error: err});
    });
});
```

This case just checks if the parameter is a number and the user is not 'user' (then its admin I assume) and then queries by id. Otherwise it queries by title

so /songs/9248 and /songs/hala_madrid works

Comment: No, I only receive one parameter which could be either `id` or `title`